# The type or namespace crystalreports could not be found in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

[image: screenshot]

Here I have added a new crystal report in my old project in which the error is getting displayed. Any help would be appreciated. I have installed VS2008 in Win11 now. My Windows applications are working fine.

Comment: VS 2008 is ancient (15 years old) and unsupported. Crystal Reports isn't included in Visual Studio for over a decade. It may have been removed in VS 2008 or even earlier, when Microsoft released its own Reporting Services. If you don't actually install Crystal Reports support in Visual Studio you won't be able to use it.

Comment: Did you actually install Crystal Reports along with Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Yes it got installed along with Visual Studio 2008 itself. My windows application with same crystal reports are working fine.

Comment: It doesn't matter what Winforms does. Web and windows applications are completely different, use different classes and different reporting engines. In a web app a report is rendered as HTML, not drawn directly on the client screen. Did you actually install the *Web* version of Crystal Reports?

Comment: In any case the error complains that the report itself is missing. How did you create the report in the first place?

Comment: In my another form the report is getting displayed. But the newly added reports is showing the error - The type or namespace crystalreports could not be found

Comment: The error complains that `CrystalReports3` can't be found. That's the name of a generated report class. That means that specific report doesn't exist for whatever reason. Perhaps it was created in a different namespace? Perhaps it had an error and was never generated? Have you tried searching for the text `CrystalReports3` in the solution?